# Unable to login to guacamole

Tags: apache, spring-boot, guacamole

I am very new to the `guacamole` project. I installed it following instruction online. But I am not able to login to the guacamole application. The instructions I followed are,

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo ufw enable

sudo ufw allow 22 && sudo ufw allow 8080

sudo apt-get install fail2ban build-essential htop libcairo2-dev     libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libossp-uuid-dev tomcat7 -y

sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-dev libpango1.0-dev libssh2-1-dev libtelnet-dev libvncserver-dev libpulse-dev libssl-dev libvorbis-dev -y

sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/guacamole/files/current/source/guacamole-server-0.9.8.tar.gz

tar -xzf guacamole-server-0.9.8.tar.gz 
cd guacamole-server-0.9.8/

sudo ./configure --with-init-dir=/etc/init.d && sudo make && sudo make    install

sudo ldconfig

sudo update-rc.d guacd defaults

sudo mkdir /etc/guacamole

sudo gedit /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties

sudo gedit /etc/guacamole/user-mapping.xml

sudo mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/.guacmole

sudo ln -s /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties /usr/share/tomcat7/.guacmole

sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/guacamole/files/current/binary/guacamole-0.9.8.war

sudo mv guacamole-0.9.8.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/guacamole.war

sudo service guacd start 

sudo service tomcat7 start
```

My `user-mapping.xml` file is configured as below,

```
<user-mapping> 
<authorize username="sandesha" password="sandy" >
<connection name="RDP">
<protocol>rdp</protocol>
<param name="hostname">103.5.133.3</param> 
<param name="port">22</param> 
</connection> 
</authorize> 
</user-mapping>
```

When I hit `localhost:8080/guacamole`, I am getting one login screen, but if I enter the credential information I configured in `user-mapping.xml`, it is throeing `invalid-credential` error. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting indicates that the Guacamole application cannot find user-mapping.xml file. Normally, this file is stored in the following locations:

- directory specified by system property guacamole.home
- directory specified by environment variable GUACAMOLE_HOME
- directory .guacamole located in the tomcat home directory

From the instructions you have posted it looks like you are using the last option. However, your directory is '.guacmole' with one 'a' missing. The two lines from your instructions should be:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/.guacamole
sudo ln -s /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties /usr/share/tomcat7/.guacamole
```